# TelegramClient не возвращает ничего в ответ

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Проблема с `Telethon`: пытаюсь зайти из-под своего аккаунта с верно скопированными с [оф сайта](https://my.telegram.org) айди и хэшом, но не получаю никакого ответа от `TelegramClient`
Да, **VPN стоит**.

```
api_id = 123456
api_hash = '12345abcdef'

from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
from telethon.tl.functions.photos import UploadProfilePhotoRequest
from config import *

print ('session start')
client = TelegramClient("session", api_id, api_hash) # дальше этой строки код не исполняется
print ('get client')
client.start()
print ('client starts')
```

Comment: ну так а что в консоль выводит? На этом этапе должно запросить номер телефона телеграм

Comment: вы должны ввести номер, а потом код

Comment: @danilshik разве это делается не при получении id и hash на сайте? В консоль не выводит ничего: нет никакого ответа от TelegramClient

Comment: @Alexldest нет, там вы просто регистрируете свое приложение. Попробуйте запустить через прокси (не через VPN)

Comment: @danilshik а куда и каким образом нужно вводить номер и код? Можно подробнее

Comment: @Alexldest в консоли должно запросить после выполнения метода .start()